# setVisibility does not work

Tags: show-hide, calendarview

While toggling between VISIBLE and GONE works, e.g., for a button, it does not work for CalendarView:

CalendarView myCalendar;
....
myCalendar              = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.my_calendar);
....
           @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (myCalendar.getVisibility()== View.GONE) {
                    myCalendar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else
                {   myCalendar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                leftLayout.invalidate();
            }
        });

How can I hide and show the CalendarView?